# Defining & using array of delegates

Tags: c#

Wow, this would be so simple in C or C++. I'm trying to write a tool in C# to parse compiled C code (i.e. the assembler output) in order to calculate the stack usage of every function in an embedded system application. But that's not what's important here. How can I create an array of "function pointers" and iterate through them, calling the functions to which they point?

I have tried about 1000 variations of `delegate` and `Delegate` and `Func` and parameterized constructors and can't figure out how to get rid of all of the nasty red squiggly lines in my VS2013 editor:

```
  public struct Parser
  {
     public string platformName;
     public Delegate d_isThisPlatform;
     public Delegate d_parseAsm;

     public Parser(string platformName, Delegate isThisPlatform, Delegate parseAsm)
     {
        this.platformName = platformName;
        this.d_isThisPlatform = isThisPlatform;
        this.d_parseAsm = parseAsm;
     }
  };

  public static bool PIC32MX_GCC_isThisPlatform(string asmFileContents)
  {
     return false; // stub
  }

  public static bool PIC32MX_GCC_parseAsm(string asmFileContents)
  {
     return false; // stub
  }

  public static bool M16C_IAR_isThisPlatform(string asmFileContents)
  {
     return true; // stub
  }

  public static bool M16C_IAR_parseAsm(string asmFileContents)
  {
     return false; // stub
  }

  const Parser[] parsers =
  {
     new Parser("PIC32MX_GCC",     PIC32MX_GCC_isThisPlatform,    PIC32MX_GCC_parseAsm),
     new Parser("M16C_IAR",        M16C_IAR_isThisPlatform,       M16C_IAR_parseAsm)
  };

  public Parser findTheRightParser(string asmFileContents)
  {
     foreach(Parser parser in parsers)
     {
        if (parser.d_isThisPlatform(asmFileContents))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Using parser: ", parser.platformName);
           return parser;
        }
     }
  }
```

My current error (for the code as listed above) is "`The best overloaded method match for 'staticAnalysis.Program.Parser.Parser(string,System.Delegate,System.Delegate)' has some invalid arguments.`" I am not sold on using `System.Delegate`; if I could simply use `delegate` that would be my preference, but more important than that, I'm interested in something simple.

Comment: "Wow, this would be so simple in C or C++." First time I've heard that :-)

Comment: Why not use several classes that implement the same interface with one string property (`platformName`) and two functions?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd - Yes. To someone coming from a EE background, C "makes sense". Its basic data types, including pointers of any type, are nothing more than decorators on the most basic of all data types, the **CPU register**: on most hardware, there's really no difference between an integer & a pointer. C++, depending on features used, is only slightly removed from "making sense," and as far as raw pointers go, it's identical to C. Java & C# "make no sense". Well, not quite that bad, but they're farther removed from the hardware and it's not intuitively obvious what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @phonetagger But that's the point of higher level languages - you abstract the code away from the raw hardware.  That way you don't need completely separate code bases for apps to run on Intel, PowerPC, not to mention the variety of hardware in mobile devices now.  If you _want_ to code directly against the hardware, C++ is still an option for you.

Comment: @DStanley - I understand. I was just responding to AndrewShepherd's comment. C is certainly a simpler language than C#. To do something as simple as create a table of function pointers and scan down the table, invoking one function from each row of the table, that would be trivial in C. I suppose it's probably near-trivial in C# too, if you understand the concept, lingo, and syntax. That's not where I am yet. But thanks for your answer. Prior to your answer I'm pretty sure I tried variations of both of your options, and probably already got those "two other compiler errors" you mention.

Answer (score 2):

`Delegate` is too broad a class for what you're trying to do.  You need to specify what input(s) the delegate can expect and what output (if any) it will generate. You can either specify them as functions that take a string and return a bool:

```
  public struct Parser
  {
     public string platformName;
     public Func<string, bool> d_isThisPlatform;
     public Func<string, bool> d_parseAsm;

     public Parser(string platformName,Func<string, bool> isThisPlatform, Func<string, bool> parseAsm)
     {
        this.platformName = platformName;
        this.d_isThisPlatform = isThisPlatform;
        this.d_parseAsm = parseAsm;
     }
  };
```

or define a *specific* delegate type and declare your fields and parameters as that type:

```
  public struct Parser
  {
     public delegate bool ParseDelegate(string content);
     public string platformName;
     public ParseDelegate d_isThisPlatform;
     public ParseDelegate d_parseAsm;

     public Parser(string platformName,ParseDelegate isThisPlatform, ParseDelegate parseAsm)
     {
        this.platformName = platformName;
        this.d_isThisPlatform = isThisPlatform;
        this.d_parseAsm = parseAsm;
     }
  };
```

After you fix *that*, you're going to end up with two other compiler errors.  The fix for those is left for your learning experience...